# IMEI alternate in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, imei

I am developing an app for iPhone in which device is registered with the backend. For Android version, I was fetching the IMEI from the device and authenticating it with the IMEI stored at back end. But, Apple does not permit fetching IMEI from device, What alternate shall I use so that the authentication takes place as it is mandatory.Also, the user can change the IMEI as he wishes(for Android Version.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to generate a unique identifier for each device instead of using the IMEI.

https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

Comment: Can user  change it as per his use ?

Comment: That would be up to you to add to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Using the link Ben posted use the following code

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier]` this is universal as it uses the MAC address and then makes a hash out of it it will always be unique and no way a person can change this

If you use this code

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier]` It will create a different identifier for each app you have as it creates a hash based on bundle identity and MAC address. You can use the top one to register more than one app to the same app

Comment: it is no longer possible to mac address in İOS, right?